# Trying to turn on theme debug, but getting an error: Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error

Tags: drush

I'm new to Drupal and Drush and so am hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I tried to turn on Theme Debug with Drush:

```
drush vset theme_debug 1
```

But I keep getting an error I don't entirely understand:

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                             
Error: Declaration of Drush\Command\DrushInputAdapter::hasParameterOption() must be compatible with
Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface::hasParameterOption($values, $onlyParams = false) in
phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Command/DrushInputAdapter.php, line 27
```

I tried `drush status` too and got the same issue, so I think drush is probably broken across the board.

I tried deleting and reinstalling drush and reprovisioning my virtual box to no affect.

Would anyone know what could've gone wrong here?

(I am running Drush 8.1.7. on Drupal 7.5)

Comment: You try to reinstall the Drush. I guess you have run `composer update` on Drush folder which downloaded a latest symfony/console package.

Answer (score 0):

Update drush

```
composer require drush/drush:9.0.0-alpha1
```